# How do I implement std::ops::Index to mutate the value being indexed?

Tags: rust, operator-overloading

I want to learn how to use the `Index` trait for my toy roguelike but can't even get it to work in a useless, dummy scenario.

```
use std::ops::Index;

// Dummy struct that wraps i32
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug)]
pub struct Integer {
    pub val: i32,
}

impl Integer {
    fn new(num: i32) -> Self {
        Integer { val: num }
    }
}

// Using the index operator on an Integer should add the index to the Integer's value.
// let i = Integer::new(20);
// i[20];
// The above code should make it so i.val == 40
impl Index<Integer> for Integer {
    type Output = i32;

    // The error is in the following line:
    fn index(&self, to_add: Integer) -> &Self::Output {
        self.val + to_add.val;
    }
}

// The code causes an error before it reaches this
fn main() {
    let mut i = Integer::new(20);
    let mut n = Integer::new(30);
    println!("i[20] is: {:?}", i[n]);
}
```

I get this error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:23:55
   |
23 |       fn index(&self, to_add: Integer) -> &Self::Output {
   |  _______________________________________________________^
24 | |         self.val + to_add.val;
25 | |     }
   | |_____^ expected &i32, found ()
   |
   = note: expected type `&i32`
              found type `()`
```

I don't really know what I'm talking about but I guess that the value dies before it reaches the end of the function or something like that? I don't yet fully understand lifetimes.

I know this looks like a "NO IDEA WHAT IM DOING FIX PLS" question, but I'd love to know what I'm doing wrong here so I can learn from it.

Comment: Signature of `index` is `index(&self, Idx) -> &Self::Output`, not `index(mut self, ...) ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Editor's note: This answer applied to the original question before the OP completely changed it. It is no longer applicable to the posted question.

---

The [`Index` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html) says, emphasis mine:

> The `Index` trait is used to specify the functionality of indexing operations like `container[index]` **when used in an immutable context**.

You are attempting to *mutate* the value, which is simply not possible. You can also tell this from the signature of `index`:

```
pub trait Index<Idx> 
where
    Idx: ?Sized, 
{
    type Output: ?Sized;
    fn index(&self, index: Idx) -> &Self::Output;
}
```

There's no `mut` anywhere here; you cannot "implement" a trait with a completely different signature! You also cannot change the type of one of the arguments (in this case, `self`).

---

Bluntly put, `Index` is the **wrong** trait to use. Additionally, idiomatic Rust users would be *really* upset if you did implement the code this way; we generally aren't of the "reuse an operator for a completely different meaning" crowd.

Instead, this should just be a function with a name:

```
impl Integer {
    fn increment(&mut self, to_add: i32) {
        self.val += to_add;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could implement `DerefMut`:

```
use std::ops::{Deref, DerefMut};

impl Deref for Integer {
type Target = i32;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target { &self.val }
}

impl DerefMut for Integer {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target { &mut self.val }
}
```

And then use it like

```
let mut i = Integer::new(20);
*i += 20;
println!("i[20] is: {:?}", i);
```

Comment: I realized that and changed it to just addition instead of mutation, I'll edit the question

Comment: @omrisim210 so, you wish to invalidate the answer? That's very frowned on.

Comment: @omrisim210 for example - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266946/155423

Comment: Well, I didn't think about invalidating the answer. Should I ask a new question if this answer works for my case? Perhaps you could edit your answer (as awkward as it sounds)?

Comment: And I understand that what I'm doing is not idiomatic, but I just wanted to learn how to use `Index`. In a real world scenario I wouldn't have even wrapped `i32` in a `struct`.